# JQuery - change page background colour on button click

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, background-color

I'm very new to jquery and am trying to change the page background colour once a button is clicked.

I have searched and there are a quite a few questions on similar things, but I'm looking for an answer on a page background colour change specifically.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks, Freddie

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="text">
        CLICK THE BUTTON TO<br> CHANGE THE BACKGROUND!
    </section>

    <button id="btn">CLICK ME!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: ;
    background: #D8D8D8;
}

.text {
    color: #686868; 
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#btn {
    margin-left: 550px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

#btn:hover {
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

JS:

```
$(button).click(function() {
    $(this).css('background', '#ff0000');
)};
```

Comment: change `$(button)` to `$('#btn')` and wrap the whole thing in a `$(document).ready(function() { });` and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 4):

```
$( "#change_background" ).on( "click", function() {
  $("body").css("background-color","#000000");
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GLprR/5/) you have an example.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(button).click(function() {
    $(this).css('background', '#ff0000');
)};
```

To this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $('body').css('background', '#ff0000');
    )};
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys, but still not working. have i initialized the library correctly in the html doc?

Comment: I'm getting errors when checking page in the console. Wondering if i have used the correct jquery library?

Comment: Finally got it working, thank you all for your help! Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` to `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` if you are testing the site locally.

If you use `//`, it uses the protocol you are acessing the page with (`file://` in case of local testng).

Comment: Thank you, i missed that! I've made the update but still cant get the background to change color??

Comment: Oh, he made a little mistake. Replace the first )}; with });

Comment: Got it! I was using zgood's code but now working with this last change!